# SEAM Parametrized inputtext

Tags: combobox, seam, textinput, parameterized

I have a problem with `<h:inputText>`. In particular I have a series of inputtext, combobox, calendar on an xhtml page.

Each of them has the value attribute like follow `value="#{myBean.first}"`, `value="#{myBean.second}"`, and so on.

In this manner myBean must have an enormous number of setter and getter.
I need to use only one setter and only one getter like the following:

```
public void setValue(String theId, String theValue){}
public String getValue(String theId){}
```

So in these only two methods I use a Map with key=theId and value=theValue inserted by user.

My question is how can do this in xhtml page?
That's how value-tag would be? Is there a special notice for passing a parameter to setter/getter?

Note that the "parameter" added to the inputText could be an object.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the key/value pairs in a Map, you can reference the map directly in your UI components. Say your backing bean has this:

```
public Map<String, Object> getDataMap() { return dataMap; }
public void setDataMap(Map<String,Object> dataMap) { this.dataMap = dataMap; }
```

Your xhtml could look like this:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.dataMap['first']}" />

<h:inputText value="#{myBean.dataMap['second']}" />
```

Comment: Great Jeremiah! Thank you, it goes!